# How can I extract confidence intervals from ezBoot (ez package)?

Tags: r, package

I am using the [`ezBoot` function](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ez/docs/ezBoot) from the `ez` package. I would like to extract the confidence intervals that are plotted with the `ezPlot2` function of the same package.

An example can be found in the [`ezBoot` function](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ez/docs/ezBoot):

```
#Read in the ANT data (see ?ANT).
data(ANT)
head(ANT)
ezPrecis(ANT)

#Run ezBoot on the accurate RT data
rt = ezBoot(
    data = ANT
    , dv = rt
    , wid = subnum
    , within = .(cue,flank)
    , between = group
    , iterations = 1e1 #1e3 or higher is best for publication
)


#plot the full design
p = ezPlot2(
    preds = rt
    , x = flank
    , split = cue
    , col = group
)
print(p)
```

How do I extract the confidence intervals?

Comment: Could you provide a minimal, complete and verifiable example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I didn't read the complete set of arguments for the [`ezPlot2` function] (http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/ez/docs/ezPlot2). To be fair the initial description says that the functions is for displaying, however if the parameter `do_plot` is set to true then it will return the point predictions (I am guessing it is the averages) and confidence intervals:

> `do_plot:` Logical. If TRUE, no plot will be produced but instead a data frame
>   containing point predictions and confidence limits will be returned.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, ezPlot2 manual is confusing.

in the parameters description it states:

*do_plot: Logical. If TRUE, no plot will be produced but instead a data frame containing point predictions and confidence limits will be returned.*

while in Value desc it states:

*If do_plot is TRUE (default) and print_code if FALSE (default), a printable/modifiable ggplot2 object representing the predictions and confidence intervals. If do_plot is FALSE or print_code is TRUE, a list containing the cell predictions and bootstrapped CIs is returned.*

The second statement is correct. Assuming, e.g., a two-factors design,
I could got CI in this way:

```
values <- ezPlot2(preds = ezboot_output, x = factor1, split = factor2, do_plot=FALSE, print_code=TRUE)
ci_lo  <- values$boot_stats$lo
ci_hi  <- values$boot_stats$hi
```